# Cross-referencing a type with Apollo Federation across multiple sub-graphs

Tags: graphql, apollo, subgraph, apollo-federation

I am new to Apollo Federation and I am having the following issue / question:

In Subgraph **A** I have the following:

```js
type Product @key(fields: "id") { {
   id: ID!
   title: String
}
```

In Subgraph **B** I have the following:

```js
type Product @key(fields: "id") { {
   id: ID!
   related: [Product]
}
```

When I run my query like this:

```js
query Product($productId: ID!) {
  product(id: $productId) {
    id
    title
    related {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the expected results, but as soon as I now want to also get the title values for the related, i.e. when running such query

```js
query Product($productId: ID!) {
  product(id: $productId) {
    id
    title
    related {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}
```

I start seeing the following error
`"Cannot return null for non-nullable field Product.title."`

Any ideas, into which keywords to look or what I might be missing here to get the title value for related products from Service **A**?

Was reading some further Apollo Federation materials and looking out for some more examples, but did not really find any good pointer unfortunately.